# Click event on view not firing in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

In my controller, I populate a `TableView` with rows dynamically by building up an array of `TableViewRow` and populating it with a View & Image.

Here's the code that creates the View & ImageView and a click event on the view:

```
// Create product image view
var productImageView = Titanium.UI.createView({
    borderRadius: 5,
    left: 10,
    top: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    width: 130,
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    productName: Name,
    imageUrl: ThumbnailUrl,
});
productImageView.add(Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    defaultImage: 'image-missing',
    image: ThumbnailUrl
}));
productImageView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.source.productName && e.source.imageUrl) {
        Alloy.createController('view_product_image', { ProductName: e.source.productName, ImageUrl: e.source.imageUrl }).getView().open({
            modalTransitionStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.MODAL_TRANSITION_STYLE_COVER_VERTICAL,
            modalStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.MODAL_PRESENTATION_FORMSHEET
        });
    } else {
        console.log('data not set');
    }
});
```

When this code runs, within the table row, I can see the image. When I click it, nothing happens. I tried attaching the click event on the ImageView directly also but still nothing happens.

Any ideas why the click event is not getting fired? Should I be subscribing to a different event instead?

Comment: you can try attaching the productName and imageUrl attributes to the TableViewRow object directly, instead of productImageView. And add the listener to TableView.

Answer (score 2):

You are not receiving click event because your event source is **imageview** and it has no **productName** and imageUrl **property**.

To receive click event of view, you need to set touchEnabled property to false of your image view.

```
productImageView.add(Titanium.UI.createImageView({
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    defaultImage: 'image-missing',
    image: ThumbnailUrl,
    touchEnabled :false
}));
```

however I think instead of adding a listener to each view you can add a common Listener to tableView and handle the event based on e.source.productName property as suggested by others.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works for me on iOS and Android. 
Maybe, can you show the TableView creation?

However, although your solution is correct, it is preferable and more efficient to add a event listener at your TableView not inside a TableViewRow due the number of listeners that will be created, then to reduce the scope of your click event only to the image, You check if the `e.source` has the `productName` and `imageURL` properties (e.g), otherwise you can infer that the click was outside the image.

Try like this:

```
$.tableView.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.source.productName && e.source.imageUrl)
        console.log('hit')
});
```